# CodeChef: Holes in the Text

Tags: java

I am working on the following [CodeChef question](https://www.codechef.com/problems/HOLES):

> Chef wrote some text on a piece of paper and now he wants to know how
>   many holes are in the text. What is a hole? If you think of the paper
>   as the plane and a letter as a curve on the plane, then each letter
>   divides the plane into regions. For example letters "A", "D", "O",
>   "P", "R" divide the plane into two regions so we say these letters
>   each have one hole. Similarly, letter "B" has two holes and letters
>   such as "C", "E", "F", "K" have no holes. We say that the number of
>   holes in the text is equal to the total number of holes in the letters
>   of the text. Help Chef to determine how many holes are in the text.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line contains a single integer T <= 40, the number of test
>   cases. T test cases follow. The only line of each test case contains a
>   non-empty text composed only of uppercase letters of English alphabet.
>   The length of the text is less then 100. There are no any spaces in
>   the input.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each test case, output a single line containing the number of
>   holes in the corresponding text.
>
> **Example**
>
> *Input:*
>   2
>   CODECHEF
>   DRINKEATCODE
>
> *Output:*
>   2
>   5

I am submitting the below code, but the judge keeps showing wrong answer (WA). Any advice?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class test {
    static short[] srr=new short[41];

    public static short getHoles(String st){
        short holes=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
            char c= st.charAt(i);
            if(c=='A') holes++;

            if(c=='D') holes++;

            if(c=='P') holes++;

            if(c=='O') holes++;

            if(c=='R') holes++;

            if(c=='Q') holes++;

            if(c=='B'){
                holes++;
                holes++;
            }
        }

        return holes;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader s = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        short cases;
        String stt= s.readLine();
        cases=Short.parseShort(stt);
        String temp;
        short t;
        for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
            temp=s.readLine();
            t = getHoles(temp);
            srr[i]=t;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i< 45; i++) {
            if(srr[i]==0) break;
            System.out.println(srr[i]); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what expected output is and sample inputs? Start with that. Then learn how to use a debugger and set a breakpoint so you can step through your code. Or even simply set printlines through the code so you can see the state of your variables at various points. Use paper and pencil to see what you think it should do(manually trace) and compare to your debugger/printlines.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    public class Letter {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InputStreamReader is= new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(is);
            int n= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                int holes=0;
                String s= br.readLine();
                char[] ch= s.toCharArray();
                for(int j=0;j<ch.length;j++) {
                    
                    if(ch[j]=='A'||ch[j]=='D'||ch[j]=='O'||ch[j]=='Q'||ch[j]=='P'||ch[j]=='R') {
                        holes= holes+1;
                    }
                    else if(ch[j]=='B') {
                        holes=holes+2;  
                    }
                    else {
                        holes=holes+0;
                    }
                }
            System.out.println(holes);  
            }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this part

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
        if (srr[i] == 0)
            break;
        System.out.println(srr[i]);

    }
```

if your word have 0 Holes you won't say 0.

try this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        System.out.println(srr[i]);

    }
```

Comment: but if i use byte datatype instead of short to reduce my memory usage, it again shows wrong answer. what can be done to optimize the memory usage for the solution.

Comment: A improvement would make "static short[] srr=new short[41]" dynamic. so you wont always have to make a 41 array long. Saying this when you get cases you cant do:  srr=new short[cases];

Comment: I am thinking, you don't have to have an array. You cant print the answer at the end of the first "for".

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i< 45; i++) {
    if(srr[i]==0) break;
    System.out.println(srr[i]);

}
```

For an input string with zero holes you leave the for loop.
For the input

```
2
EEEE
CODECHEF
```

nothing would be printed.
Since you don't use `srr` anywhere except in the main you can remove the static and put it in the main method.
`cases` indicates how large `srr` needs to be so you can initialize `srr` with it and change the for loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i< cases; i++) {
    System.out.println(srr[i]);
}
```